# iOS IAP issue - when user has to confirm credit card, iOS remains on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

We are encountering an occasional issue which runs thus:

- A user's first purchase on a new device happens to be an IAP using our app
- iOS asks them to confirm their credit card details because they've not used the device before.
- It appears to take them to the App Store app to fill in these details
- When they've done this, they are left sitting in the app store
- If they manually return to our app, the purchase has failed, but they have been charged
- Restarting the app doesn't help

We have spotted revisions which should help, but has anyone else had an issue with iOS not coming back to their app in this situation, and possibly therefore not communicating the purchase success?

What is the IAP process if a user returns to the app manually?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how you've implemented your `SKPaymentTransaction` observer?

Comment: Thanks for coming back so swiftly. I am not actually the coder on this project, so I may not be able to supply that info, which in turn doesn't help you help, apologies. Meantime, if anyone has a similar experience it would be of interest.

Comment: I've added some more info in an answer (it won't fit in the comments). StoreKit is designed to handle this situations, so it sounds as if maybe there is something up with how your app is coded to handle purchases.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd recommend having your coder come here and maybe talk a bit about how you're implementing `StoreKit`. The system is designed to cope with edge cases where users are taken away from the app and don't go back, but you have to implement the `SKPaymentTransaction` observer correctly. A common mistake initialise the transaction observer when the user goes to purchase an item, but this is wrong. The observer needs to be around from application launch.